# HTML Dropdown not working in android webview but it is in android mobile chrome

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

below is the HTML code

```
<div class="f-l" style="margin-top:8px;">
    <ul class="sa_page_ndx">
        <li class="">
            <div class="btn-group open">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle sa_pagelist" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="f-l drp_mob">Browse All Categories</span><span class="f-l sa_dpico"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="category">
                    <li cat_id="0" class="active"><a>Browse All Categories</a></li>
    <li cat_id="19"><a>BABY (2)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="13"><a>BAKE SHOPPE (6)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="4"><a>BEER &amp; WINE (12)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="5"><a>DAIRY (16)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="12"><a>DELI (12)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="11"><a>FLORAL (2)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="6"><a>FROZEN (20)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="1"><a>GROCERY (40)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="15"><a>HEALTH &amp; BEAUTY (9)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="3"><a>HOME CARE (8)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="7"><a>MEAT (14)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="2"><a>OTHER - SPECIAL SECTION (3)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="18"><a>PET (1)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="10"><a>PRODUCE (14)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="9"><a>SEAFOOD (5)</a></li>
    <li cat_id="8"><a>SERVICE MEAT (5)</a></li>
                </ul>
```

and Android code i used is

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   // webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    this.webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    this.webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    this.webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    this.webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
            //  view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {  document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-static-top')[0].style.display=" + "\"none\"; " + "})()");
            load_progresbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Constants.showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description);
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

When i click on dropdown its showing list but unable to perform action on list item click and simply hiding the list.Same action working in android chrome

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Browser's rendering of s is buggy and will remove the normal styling if a background or border is applied.

Since s not looking like s is a pretty big usability issue, your best bet is to not style them for this browser only.

Unfortunately, there's no pure CSS way of selecting/excluding the Android Browser, so I recommend you use Layout Engine (https://github.com/stowball/Layout-Engine), which will add a class of .browser-android to the  tag.

You could then style all s except on Android Browser, like so:

```
html:not(.browser-android) select {
   background: #0f0;
   border: 1px solid #ff0;
}
```